# Is tagging a question [excel-vba] preferable to tagging it [excel] [vba]?

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions relating to using VBA to automate Excel, the tags `excel`, `vba` and `excel-vba` are often used.

Not all `excel` questions relate to `vba` and not all `vba` questions relate to `excel`. Where a question does relate to both Excel and VBA, should it be tagged with:

- `excel` `vba` = 966 questions on SO
  right now
- `excel-vba`  = 906 questions    on SO
  right now
- `excel` `vba` `excel-vba`  = 263 questions on SO right
  now (subset of each of the above
  categories)

Should one particular way of tagging be preferred over the other here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I work a lot in those tags, and think that when a question is about VBA in Excel, we should use the tags `Excel` and `VBA`.  It'd be nice if the `excel-vba` tag just went away.  It might be nice if the `excel-vba` tag synonymed to `VBA`, though it's not a perfect solution.

Comment: Of course, the perfect solution would be to synonym to both `excel` and `vba`.

Comment: @Andy, sure, but I doubt the system is setup for 2 to 1 tag synonyms.

Comment: Thanks - there seem to be similar issues with the analogous tags for Word and Access

Comment: @barrowc, I went ahead and created the tag-synonyms for excel-vba, word-vba and access-vba.

Comment: @Lance Roberts, I have up voted your suggestions at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms, but 2 more votes are needed.

Comment: @Remou, thanks, I left a message for Dick K, but he hasn't voted yet.

Comment: @Remou I propose [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model?lq=1) that [excel-vba] be synonymed to [excel-objects] or [excel-object-model].

Answer (score 16):

There is a difference between Excel questions (which concern worksheets, mostly), VBA questions (which concern a programming language used by several Office apps), and Excel-VBA questions (which concern that programming language used in the context of Excel, the Excel object model, etc).

They are three different things, and not every question is about all of them.

Making excel-vba a synonym for VBA was an abuse of the synonym system, so that synonym has been deleted. The result was that people tagged things excel-vba which was silently changed to vba, and we lost information in the process.

Using "excel" and "vba" tags on Excel VBA questions is not appropriate if the question isn't really about using Excel or programming Excel worksheets.

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on this issue, but the current [tag:access-vba] -> [tag:vba] synonym might also be up for reconsideration based on this (especially since it [already caused some trouble](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110248/my-subscription-to-access-vba-sends-emails-for-vba) for someone).

Comment: yeah, we're deleting the synonyms for access-vba and word-vba too, for the same reason.

Comment: I don't get it at all.  How would a question on 'Excel VBA' not be about using 'Excel or programming Excel worksheets'.  Anytime you have a question about Excel VBA, you have a question about both 'Excel' and 'VBA'.

Comment: So all my work to clean up those tags was for naught.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - A question about Excel VBA is about *both* topics. The synonym [excel-vba]->[vba] lost the information that the question was about Excel.  AFAIK, there's no mechanism to split the tag into two, the change will have to be done manually.

Comment: @LanceRoberts we certainly appreciate the work. I agree that it's an imperfect system. The trouble was that our "synonym" feature really only works when there are genuine synonyms, not when there are shades of meaning...

Comment: @Kevin, if you look at my answer you'll see that I would always have the application tag also.  Tag synonyms don't change existing tags.

Comment: Looking at this issue again today, there are 188 questions found with `[macros] [excel] -[vba] -[excel-vba]` Indeed Joel answered one of them (#7986823) yesterday. How does the `macros` tag fit into all of this?

Comment: @KevinVermeer I propose synonymizing/replacing [excel-vba] with [excel-objects] or [excel-object-model] [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).

Comment: But "pure" Excel questions are off-topic for SO, so tagging a question with [excel] in the context of SO obviously means programmatically manipulating Excel objects. In that case, what is the difference between [excel]+[vba] and [excel-vba]?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it would be nice if there was a synonym from: [excel-vba] -> [excel] , [vba]

However the synonym system does not support this at the moment. I think that doing a blanket kill of the [excel-vba] tag is a **bad** idea as we will lose information.

Comment: It is possible to request such a feature? I have other examples ([wpf] [binding] vs. [wpf-binding], transfering [wpf-binding] to [binding] as someone suggested would loose the [wpf] for all the questions not tagged [wpf] (there are such questions).)

Comment: There is certainly value in [excel-vba], but only inasmuch as it means [excel-objects] or [excel-object-model]. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/rename-or-otherwise-replace-foo-vba-to-foo-object-model).