# VBA : Increasingly Specific Tags

Tags: discussion

Related to: [Is tagging a question [excel-vba] preferable to tagging it [excel] [vba]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62868/is-tagging-a-question-excel-vba-preferable-to-tagging-it-excel-vba)

I have notices that people are increasingly tagging questions `access-vba`, `excel-vba` and so forth. A lot of VBA works with all Office applications, so I think it would be better to only have a `vba` tag, which can be narrowed by the addition of the application tag, when required. Referring to the related question above, it seems that this may be a popular choice.

Is adding meta tags the best way to deal with this?

EDIT: Tag synonyms have been added at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms, thanks to Lance Roberts.

Comment: If you agree with this suggestion and have an answer score of five or more, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms

Comment: I've now got a tag synonym setup for `worksheet-function` to synonym `excel-formula` to it, so we can standardize on the more generic tag to cover other spreadsheets also.  You can vote for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/worksheet-function/synonyms).

Comment: *sigh* I do not have the required score on this tag to vote. This is a bit daft, surely at some point rep should override this limitation on sub- and minor tags?

Comment: I agree, I've been wanting to do a synonym on Super User for a long time now, but am still short of the 2500 needed.