# One-to-many tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is tagging a question [excel-vba] preferable to tagging it [excel] [vba]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62868/is-tagging-a-question-excel-vba-preferable-to-tagging-it-excel-vba)

I've just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241021/how-to-loop-over-a-multi-row-column-range-per-column-using-excel-2007-vba/4) that has the following tags and thought a retag would be appropriate:

excel, vba, excel-vba, excel-2007

Given we have tags already for Excel and VBA, it seems sensible to retag any questions with "excel-vba" (or word-vba, etc for that matter) as a question about "Excel" and "VBA".  My problem is that the retag suggestion box only allows me to enter one replacement tag.  Is this a limitation, something for moderators only or something we could look to implement?

Comment: Nuts. Don't have enough rep on here to create a new tag, "synonym".  Probably for the best, really.

Comment: What do you believe the tags should be? I think all Office + VBA questions should have the generic VBA tag, a generic application tag (Excel, Word etc) and a specific application tag, where relevant (Excel-2007 etc). I mentioned it here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70296/vba-increasingly-specific-tags and also cite another thread with a similar stance.

Comment: @waiwai933 - It seems this is almost an exact duplicate.  Feel free to close this, except there doesn't really seem to be any commitment to correct the tags themselves. Only a recognition that it's not the ideal situation.

Comment: @Remou - I agree with you.  The tags should be "Application" "VBA".  Not hyphenated combinations of the two.

Comment: If you have a total answer score of 5 or more, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms.