# Why did my tag-synonyms disappear?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I had created tag synonyms for [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), of [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba), [word-vba](/questions/tagged/word-vba) and [access-vba](/questions/tagged/access-vba) and they had one vote sitting on them.  I was just trying to recruit another vote, when I went there and noticed my synonyms had completely disappeared.

Could we get a full explanation of what's going on?  What's the point of trying to do cleanup on my niche tags, if it will all be for naught?

Answer (score 3):

I nuked them. see: [Synonyms mean interchangeable, not similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59285/synonyms-mean-interchangeable-not-similar)

My reasoning was that `excel-vba` relates to particular issues with the vba object model that are relevant for excel only (like looking up a worksheet) and so on.

Comment: __Did you look at the related questions first__, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62868/is-tagging-a-question-excel-vba-preferable-to-tagging-it-excel-vba) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70662/one-to-many-tag-synonyms)?

Comment: VBA is not PHP, maybe you could quiz the other VBA guys first before doing something like that.

Comment: @waffles, certainly before the switch gets done, there should be a look to make sure that all of those with `excel-vba` have an `excel` tag there also.  Most do, but there could be a quick add of that tag for those that don't, so that information isn't lost.  Once the transition is done, then people will naturally add the `excel` tag on, once they see that their tag gets synonymed.

Comment: Was it from orbit?

Comment: @Lance ... synonyms affect the future ... some poor guy is going to tag his stuff excel-vba and not understand why we stripped off the excel part.

Comment: @waffles, yes, but that happens with quite a few tag synonyms, it's the nature of the beast.

Comment: @Lance do you have any examples where we strip information ... the weirdest edge case I know of is 'fast' -> 'performance' it still kind of makes sense ... but removing the word excel and expecting users to magically know to use it as a separate tag is a pretty big leap.

Comment: @waffles, let me navigate the maze to get to the synonym page and I'll see if I can find one, though I don't know if it even shows confirmed synonyms.

Comment: @waffles, here's what I found on the first half of the first page of active synonyms:  960.gs, adobe-flex, adobe-flash, apache-ant, apache-cassandra; all of those have been stripped down to shorter tags.

Comment: Has this every been resolved or did you just give up @LanceRoberts?

Comment: @Lankymart, nothing was changed from this answer. And since then Joel changed the whole Excel/VBA tagging system, so I gave up trying to clean things up.