# My subscription to "access-vba" sends emails for "vba"

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, subscription

I'm a little puzzled. I've subscribed to the tag access-vba but not to the tag vba. However, the emails I am getting show that the questions are simply tagged vba, not access-vba.

Is there an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[access-vba](/questions/tagged/access-vba) has been [made a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/synonyms) of the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) tag, so the system considers them to be the same.

Ideally you'd at least be able to create and subscribe to a [tag filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular) for just questions tagged [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) and get results similar to those you were expecting, but unfortunately it seems like there's no way to limit filter results to only questions containing all of the specified tags.

Comment: Related feature request: [Email subscription to a combination of tags (using AND operator)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78107)

Comment: I admit this is very unhandy. 99% of all the posts in VBA are about Excel which I'm not really interested in. So that means the access-vba tag is just plain irrelevant.